# How to get JDialog textFiels Value from JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

Hi I am new in Java coding and trying to design a user friendly desktop App with the help of JFrame and JDialog -

My JFrame is -

```
package com.myapp.ui;
    
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;

public class MyFrame extends JFrame { 

private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyFrame() {

        setTitle("MyFrame");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JButton btnClickMe = new JButton("Click Me");
        btnClickMe.setBounds(271, 171, 115, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnClickMe);
        
        JCheckBox chckbxOpenDialog = new JCheckBox("Open Dialog");      
        chckbxOpenDialog.setBounds(25, 171, 139, 29);
        contentPane.add(chckbxOpenDialog);
        
        chckbxOpenDialog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(chckbxOpenDialog.isSelected()== true){
                    MyDialog MD = new MyDialog();
                    MD.setModal(true);
                    MD.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        });
        
        btnClickMe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                 //Here I want to get the value of textFieldName and textFieldEmail from JDialog
                 //after Click on Confirm Button in JDialog and closing/disposing it
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My JDialog is -

```
package com.myapp.ui;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class MyDialog extends JDialog {

    private final JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
    private JTextField textFieldName;
    private JTextField textFieldEmail;
    private JButton btnConfirm;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
            dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            dialog.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public MyDialog() {
        setTitle("MyDialog");
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        getContentPane().add(contentPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contentPanel.setLayout(null);
        
        textFieldName = new JTextField();
        textFieldName.setBounds(108, 26, 146, 26);
        contentPanel.add(textFieldName);
        textFieldName.setColumns(10);
        
        textFieldEmail = new JTextField();
        textFieldEmail.setBounds(108, 68, 146, 26);
        contentPanel.add(textFieldEmail);
        textFieldEmail.setColumns(10);
        
        btnConfirm = new JButton("Confirm");
        btnConfirm.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //passing the Name and Email field value in JFrame
            }
        });
        btnConfirm.setBounds(132, 141, 115, 29);
        contentPanel.add(btnConfirm);
        
        MyFrame MF = new MyFrame();
        
    }
}
```

Both the JFrame and JDialog are in the same package. I am trying to get the value of

textFieldName and textFieldEmail from JDialog to JFrame

if any one can guide me the best possible way, would be relly great.

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). A tip related to that: `new JTextField()` should be more like `new JTextField(12)`. The `12` indicates how many letters (columns) that text field is intended to handle before being filled & helps determine the size.

Comment: .. Once a GUI is laid out properly, this `setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);` (which is at best a guess) can be replaced by `pack(); // makes it exactly the size it needs to be`. Packing a GUI should be done after all components are added.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Add setters to MyFrame
2. Pass `MyFrame` reference to `MyDialog` (using `this`) when it is created in the `ActionListener`
3. In the `ActionListener` in `MyDialog` set fields in `MyFrame`

There are probably better ways to do this. The built in `JOptionPane` produces modal dialog windows that wait for user input. These would be better rather than passing references of JFrames to JDialog.

Also note that `JavaFX` has largely replaced Java `Swing` for desktop UIs

Comment: Thank you @tomgeraghty3 the code I shared is a working code. Any possibility tha you can add the changes you have mentioned. I am very new and have very limited understanding on java coding.